# python pyserial optimisation

Tags: python, pyserial

I am read some data from serial port. Data are packed as 9 char. Not need for struct, I know wat the format is, but have 2 problems:
1) If I keep the port open, the answer is 1-3 seconds after the event(there is a led-panel where I can see in real time events and values that shoud be on serial). I supose it is related to some buffer that flush only when full(and I am force to work on Win32 as non-admin, so not very much control of that). The reading is perform periodicaly (200 ms) so opening/closing seems like a waste of resources. Is there a way of keeping the port open and just force the buffer to flush before reading?(from python!)

2)In order to get the values, I have to find a marker - 13 - as the end of struct, and read acordingly(next 8 char or previous 8). Looping is not most eficient python part, so is it a way of geting the index, and reading data without blocking everythings? (A continous read keep processor up, even if in other thread as non-blocking solution).
If for any use:

```
class SeReader(object):
    def __init__(self, tata):
        self.ser = serial.Serial()
        self.ser.baudrate = 2400
        self.ser.port = "COM1"
        self.tata = tata # entry point for main gui notification
        self.val, self.status, self.semn, self.data, self.oldVal = None, None, None, None, None
        self.is_stable, self.on = False, False
        self.stable_count = 0
        self.on = False

    def read(self):
        if not self.on: return False
        self.ser.open()
        data = self.ser.read(18)
        self.ser.close()
        start = -1
        for x in xrange(18):
            if data[x] == '\r':
                start = x + 1
                break
        if start == -1:return True
        self.data = val = data[start:start + 9]
        try:
            self.status = val[0]
            self.val = val[2:8]
            self.semn = val[1]
            self.tata.write_data(self.semn, self.val)
        except Exception as e:
            self.tata.set_cs_unstable()
            self.tata.write_data("> ", "Eroare")
            print(self.val, e)
        if self.val == self.oldVal:
            self.stable_count += 1
        else:
            self.oldVal = self.val
            self.stable_count = 0
        if self.stable_count > 8:self.tata.set_cs_stable()
        else:self.tata.set_cs_unstable()
        return True
```

the self.tata and stuff are for notify the main GUI

Answer (score 0):

I use a check of my_serial.inWaiting() to find out if there are any bytes waiting to be read then read them all in a separate thread which then raises an event with the received data attached.

Once I have a block of data I can search it for a given start/end sequence using regular expressions, (re), if the blocks are mixed in with other data.

Comment: may be the solution for 1). This way, I can keep track of changes even between the 200ms reads. I will try a few hours later(now I am not near to device).Thanks.

Comment: Your answer forced me to made some tests. The buffer is 4096 so is faster to open/close connection and read the value(all I need is 9 bytes at a time). Remember, I only need the value at read time, not all data (the device "spit" it's value regard if is asked or not). I'm trying to move this to cython, the function call is much light than in python but the drawback is that I made that function call from GUI, so no cython optimisation. Your answer force me to use a IDE, too. If I do this from the begening, the inWaiting() function were common to me ...